# Error in setting default route page to Home page in App.js - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm new to React Native and I want to set the default screen to Home Screen in my application.

This is my Home Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
      <Text>Hello! I'm Home component</Text>
     </View>
   );
  }
}

export default Home
```

The following is my App.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Home } from './app/components/Home';

export default createStackNavigator({
   home: Home
});
```

After building it throws the following error in emulator.

The component for route 'home' must be a React component. Can somebody tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Fix like this:

```
import Home from './app/components/Home';
```

Comment: Because in your `Home` component, you used `export default`, hence, we have to `import` it like that. I think you should take a quick look at this: [Using the default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export)

Answer (score 1):

You are importing Home wrongly in App.js

It should be `import Home from './app/components/Home';`

Default exports don't need to be destructured in files in which they are imported.

This article can provide more insight: https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: Yeah.. didn't notice it. Unlike Angular it's different